# How to change imagesize to allow longer audio (wav to png)

Tags: python

Wondering if someone could help me out with something simple.
I am running a script that converts a WAV file into a PNG, the problem im having is that I can't load a WAV file longer than 1 second.

I need to change imageSize = math.sqrt(44100) to increase the allowed image size, but I'm not really sure how to go about it. I'd like to load a 60 second WAV file instead.

I've tried math.sqrt(44100*60) But I still get a 55KB output PNG. (the 60 second audio file is 5MB)
The code:

```
from PIL import Image
import wave, struct, sys, math

##
# Collect input
##
if sys.argv[1][-4:] != '.wav':
    sys.exit("First argument should be a .wav file")

if sys.argv[2][-4:] != '.png':
    sys.exit("Second argument should be a .png file")

##
# Conversion:
##

# Wave file needs to be 16 bit mono
waveFile = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

if waveFile.getnchannels() != 1:
    sys.exit("ERROR: The wave file should be single channel (mono)")

if waveFile.getframerate() != 44100:
    sys.exit("ERROR: The samplerate should be 44,100")

imageRgbArray = list()

waveLength = waveFile.getnframes()

# Create the image size (based on the length)
imageSize = math.sqrt(44100)

# Loop through the wave file
for i in range(0, 44100):

    # Try to read frame, if not possible fill with 0x0
    try:
        waveData = waveFile.readframes(1)
        data = struct.unpack("<h", waveData) # This loads the wave bit
        convertedData = int(data[0]) + 32768 # This adds 16bit/2 (=32768) to the data
    except:
        convertedData = 0
        pass

    # This converts the number into a hex value.
    convertedDataHex = hex(convertedData)

    # convert the value to a string and strips first two characters
    hexString = str(convertedDataHex)[2:]

    # Check how much the string should be prefixed to get the color hex length (= 6 char)
    count = 6 - len(hexString)

    # Prefix with a zero
    while (count > 0):
        hexString = "0" + hexString
        count -= 1

    # Convert into RGB value
    rgbData = tuple(int(hexString[i:i + 6 // 3], 16) for i in range(0, 6, 6 // 3)) # Convert to RGB data

    # Add the RGB value to the image array
    imageRgbArray.append(rgbData)

# Create new image
im = Image.new('RGB', (int(imageSize), int(imageSize)))

# Add image data
im.putdata(imageRgbArray)

# Save image
im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

The full project (not mine):
https://github.com/bobvanluijt/audio-convolutional-neural-network

Comment: when you manged the sqrt to `math.sqrt(44100*60)` did you also update range to `range(44100*60)`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated range. Im getting a "too many data entries error" https://pastebin.com/TviNjrV4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by changing these few lines, the problem with sqrt is it gives float and that is rounded down, so the image doesn't have enough pixels, we can prevent that by using the ceiling function.

```
...
waveLength = waveFile.getnframes()

# Create the image size (based on the length)
imageSize = math.ceil(math.sqrt(waveLength))

# Loop through the wave file
for i in range(waveLength):
    ...
```

A benefit of this approach is that we are no longer constrained to samples of a given bit rate, so you can remove.

```
if waveFile.getframerate() != 44100:
    sys.exit("ERROR: The samplerate should be 44,100")
```

Comment: Great! That worked! I have another question....how can I determine the output colour? I need for it to be binary...like only black and white, not this weird green colour

Comment: I would look into the line that sets rgbData, it sets a 3 tuple one for each RGB colour. If you want a binary image you probably want to change this, however your image will need 3x the number of pixels to hold the same amount of data.

Comment: Right....that makes sense. Ok then, maybe binary isnt what I need since thatll make it too big. How can I just change the colours, so instead of rgb, 3 colours? Say if I needed black, white and red? I need for the main colour which seems to be green to be the negative space...so white in this case.

Comment: Something like the one on the right..https://joonuryuscienceresearch.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/color-qr-code-vs-regular-qr-code-size-difference.png Where could I begin to get a colour scheme like this?