# Convert png back to wav

Tags: python

I've modified some code that takes a .wav file and turns it into a .png.

The original source for the .wav to .png conversion is from:
https://github.com/bobvanluijt/audio-convolutional-neural-network/blob/master/convertWavToPng.py
I've edited it so that instead the colors are sorted in a gradient fashion so that it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4njd.jpg

Here:

```
from PIL import Image
import wave, struct, sys, math

##
# Collect input
##
if sys.argv[1][-4:] != '.wav':
    sys.exit("First argument should be a .wav file")

if sys.argv[2][-4:] != '.png':
    sys.exit("Second argument should be a .png file")

##
# Conversion:
##

# Wave file needs to be 16 bit mono
waveFile = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

if waveFile.getnchannels() != 1:
    sys.exit("ERROR: The wave file should be single channel (mono)")


imageRgbArray = list()

waveLength = waveFile.getnframes()

# Create the image size (based on the length)
imageSize = math.ceil(math.sqrt(waveLength))

# Loop through the wave file
for i in range(waveLength):

    # Try to read frame, if not possible fill with 0x0
    try:
        waveData = waveFile.readframes(1)
        data = struct.unpack("<h", waveData) # This loads the wave bit
        convertedData = int(data[0]) + 32768
    except:
        convertedData = 0
        pass

    bits = 5
    rgbData = tuple([(convertedData>>bits*i)&(2**bits-1) for i in range(3)])
    rgbData = tuple(map(lambda x: x<<3, rgbData))

    # Add the RGB value to the image array
    imageRgbArray.append(rgbData)

# Create new image
im = Image.new('RGB', (int(imageSize), int(imageSize)))

# Add image data
im.putdata(list(sorted(imageRgbArray)))

# Save image
im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

But now I need to be able to convert the sorted .png back into a .wav file.
Luckily, I already have this to work with:
https://github.com/bobvanluijt/audio-convolutional-neural-network/blob/master/convertPngToWav.py

```
from PIL import Image
import wave, struct, sys, soundfile as Sndfile, numpy as np, math

##
# Collect input
##
if sys.argv[1][-4:] != '.png':
    sys.exit("First argument should be a .png file")

if sys.argv[2][-4:] != '.wav':
    sys.exit("Second argument should be a .wav file")

##
# Conversion:
##

# Open image
with Image.open(sys.argv[1]) as pngFile:

    # Load image
    pngAllPixels = pngFile.load()

    # Set the counters that create the image
    countX = 0
    countY = 0
    count = pngFile.size[0] * pngFile.size[1]

    # Create the array which will contain all the bits
    bitArray = list()

    # Loop through the individual pixels
    while count > 0:

        # Set the location of the pixel that should be loaded
        singlePixel = pngAllPixels[countX, countY]

        # Get RGB vals and convert them to hex
        singlePixelToHexString = '%02x%02x%02x' % (singlePixel[0], singlePixel[1], singlePixel[2])

        # Break if end of file (0x0)
        if singlePixelToHexString == "000000":
            break # break because audio is < 44100 bit

        # Convert hex string into actual hex
        singlePixelToHex = hex(int("0x" + singlePixelToHexString.lstrip("0"), 16) + int("0x0", 16))

        # This adds 16bit/2 (=32768) to the data and converts hex into a bit
        singleBit = int(singlePixelToHex, 16) - 32768

        # Append the single bit to the array
        bitArray.append(singleBit)

        # Run through the image and set x and y vals (goes to next row when ready)
        if countX == (pngFile.size[0] - 1):
            countX = 0
            countY += 1
        else:
            countX += 1
        count -= 1

    # Convert the array into a Numpy array
    bitArrayNp = np.array(bitArray, dtype=np.int16)

    # Output the file
Sndfile.write(sys.argv[2], bitArrayNp, 44100, 'PCM_16')
```

I've been told I need a way to convert each 3-byte pixel color into a two byte number to turn it back into the original wav file.

I think that means changing
`rgbData = tuple(map(lambda x: x<<3, rgbData))` back to
`rgbData = tuple(map(lambda x: x<<2, rgbData))`

But I'm not entirely sure how to implement that in the `pngtowav.py` file.
I'm new at this, so anything helps.

Comment: Due to the loss of information that occurs because of the way you're converting the wav data to image data, it'll be impossible to convert it back into its original form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way I can convert it properly without losing data but still sort the colours?

Comment: Possibly, but frankly I'm not sure what the image you're trying to create means or represents. The sorting of the data you're doing here really messes things up in that regard. I tried to figure out what the goal was while attempting to work on your other question, [How to change imagesize to allow longer audio (wav to png)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195130/how-to-change-imagesize-to-allow-longer-audio-wav-to-png), but gave up after a while because it didn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I updated the code above to accept longer audio, and it does make the image bigger. This was it before I started messing around with colour: https://pastebin.com/c4XK2qJ5  (works on any audio size) Id like to be able to organize the colours so that they are sorted together so that it is more distinguishable to a camera, like a QR code. Im not sure how to correct the loss of information though or how to read it back once the colors are rearranged.

Comment: This sounds like a cool idea, by why not use a recurrent-neural-network rather than a convolutional one.  As I understand it (and I'm certainly not an expert on the subject).  RNNs are ideal for time series data, such as audio files.  That way you won't loose any information converting from 16bit samples to 8 bit pixels.

Comment: Im not sure theres any neural network involved though? Sorry, https://github.com/bobvanluijt/audio-convolutional-neural-network isnt actually my code, im only interested in using it to convert wav's to png's and back...but instead of them looking grainy and green like they show, I was hoping to make them colorful and blocky, like a QR code.

Comment: @spacemanjosh: There's no way to convert 16-bit samples to 8-bit pixels and avoid losing information, especially when they're sorted afterwards also throws away information about their relative locations. Trying to not to do so based on the OP's stated goals is, in my option, largely a waste of time.

Comment: Jerry: Here's a thought: PNG files can have arbitrary data embedded in them that will be ignored when displaying the image. See the related question [**Is it possible to store arbitrary data in an image file?**](https://superuser.com/questions/357869/is-it-possible-to-store-arbitrary-data-in-an-image-file). This is described in detail in [RFC 2083](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2083#section-3) and it means you can put whatever you want in the image file—includingthe entire original .wav file—and read the data back later (using your own code which knows about the extra data).

Comment: @martineau I like this idea alot, but since im new to python...is it possible to just try and rerrange the colours into chunks and read them back? Thats all I'd like to do really. The code I had before here: https://pastebin.com/c4XK2qJ5 works perfectly fine on large audio files, but I guess my methods above arent quite right since you say id be losing data

Comment: Jerry: It doesn't matter how simple "all you want to do" is, once the info is destroyed, it's gone. Besides the sorting, the statement `tuple(int(hexString[i:i + 6 // 3], 16) for i in range(0, 6, 6 // 3))` is only using 6 of the 8 hex digits possible in `hexString` so some bits of the wav sample data are being thrown away forever. Do you understand the type of data that's in a wav file? I doubt it because the image you're creating doesn't seem to convey/preserve that very well. What's its purpose and why to you need to get the wav data back?

Comment: How can I make it 8 of 8 then?

Comment: Data is data in the end. But I would like to know how I can make it 8 and not 6.

Comment: @martineau `There's no way to convert 16-bit samples to 8-bit pixels` Precisely, that's what I meant, sorry if I wasn't clear.  I was recommending instead that the data be treated as a 16bit time-series of data to preserve data integrity.

Comment: Jerry: When replying to me you need to prefix my username with an `@` so I will be notified (I don't need to do that here to get your attention because it's posted under your question and happens automatically).

Comment: Jerry: While I could show you have to convert the wav sample data into a png pixel and preserve the original value, it wouldn't fix the issue caused by sorting the data.